# Weird Behaviour in C++ Snake School Assignment

Tags: c++

So over the last few weeks we've been coding snake in c++ step by step. Right now we have to implement the snake actually growing. (All of this happens in the console)

We realize the growth by saving the head and the tail of the snake, as well as the Direction the Head went on a given field and then moving the tail into that saved direction from the field the tail is on.

Theoretically skipping this tail movement once when we eat a fruit should let our snake grow.

However, my Snake either doesnt grow at all, or grows infinitely until I pass the Field on which the fruit **was** again, or ,in this current iteration, grows mostly correct but only in the direction which I was facing when eating the fruit. Also in this Iteration the size of the snake changes, if I comment out the GenerateFruit() Command (Even when that command is completely empty).

I'm clueless as to what im doing wrong. I've had different behaviour just by having a literally empty if statement.

Heres the main part of the code:

```
bool MoveSnake(SnakeDataT snakeData){

//Collision detection: If the new x/y Coordinate hits the walls we have a collision.
if (snakeData.Head.x + snakeData.dx == WIDTH - 1 || snakeData.Head.x + snakeData.dx == 0 || snakeData.Head.y + snakeData.dy == HEIGHT + 1 || snakeData.Head.y + snakeData.dy == 0)
{
    SetCursor(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Game Over" << endl;
    return false;
}



//Save current Movement Direction in current coordinate 
snakeData.Field[snakeData.Head.x][snakeData.Head.y].dx = snakeData.dx;
snakeData.Field[snakeData.Head.x][snakeData.Head.y].dy = snakeData.dy;

//Fruit Collision:
if (snakeData.Head.x == snakeData.Fruit.x && snakeData.Head.y == snakeData.Fruit.y)
{
    //GenerateFruit(snakeData); <- If I leave this out it literally changes behaviour?!
}
else if (!(snakeData.Head.x == snakeData.Fruit.x && snakeData.Head.y == snakeData.Fruit.y))
{
    //Delete at Tail Position
    SetCursor(snakeData.Tail.x, snakeData.Tail.y);
    cout << ' ';

    //Move Tail by saved Direction. I did try this with the Tail coordinates first, but after many different iterations this showed the weirdest results.
    snakeData.Tail.x += snakeData.Field[snakeData.Head.x][snakeData.Head.y].dx;
    snakeData.Tail.y += snakeData.Field[snakeData.Head.x][snakeData.Head.y].dy; 
}

//Move Head
snakeData.Head.x += snakeData.dx;
snakeData.Head.y += snakeData.dy;

//Draw Head
SetCursor(snakeData.Head.x, snakeData.Head.y);
cout << "\xCE";

return true;
```

Here are my structs:

```
#define WIDTH 30
#define HEIGHT 30

enum FieldTypeT
{
    empty,
    Snake
};

struct FieldT
{
    FieldTypeT fieldType;
    int dx;
    int dy;
};

struct PointT
{
    int &x;
    int &y;
};

struct SnakeDataT
{
    PointT Head;
    PointT Fruit;
    int &dx;
    int &dy;
    PointT Tail;
    FieldT Field[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
};
```

If you need more Insight I'll add what you need. 
Bear with me though, the Teacher is asking for questionable practices.

Comment: Why do you have unintialized references in your structures? (The `x` and `y` data members)

Comment: A [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) is the tool of choice. It's the one tool you will be using more frequently than anything else. Start using it.

Comment: The `FieldT` structure should have a `PointT` type rather than `dx` and `dy`.

Comment: Using references as you are is unconventional. I suspect the problem is that the references don't refer to what you think they do; for example with the function  `bool MoveSnake(SnakeDataT snakeData)` , you have copied by value `snakeData.Field` , however the references in that `snakeData` will still refer to the copy in the calling code, not to the `Field` in the current function

Comment: I would recommend not using references in your structs at all. To get more concrete answers you will need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Passing the snakeData as reference solved my problems, thank you.